# Generic swap function to swap strings and arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, swap, double-pointer

I am learning C by trying to implement a generic swap function which is capable of swapping strings and arrays. I think it's possible because strings and arrays are essentially arrays in memory, and I am not swapping actual bytes but only pointers. Here is my implementation:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void swap(void **a, void **b) {
    void *tmp;
    tmp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = tmp;
}

void print_array(char *c, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%c ", c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char *h = "hell";
    char *w = "world";
    printf("%s %s\n", h, w);
    swap((void **)&h, (void **)&w);
    printf("%s %s\n", h, w);

    char c[5] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    char d[3] = { '1', '2', '3' };
    print_array(c, 5);
    print_array(d, 3);
    swap((void **)&c, (void **)&d);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
hell world
world hell
a e i o u 
1 2 3 
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As you can see, this generic swap function can swap two strings, but it triggers core dumped when the inputs are arrays. I don't understand which part of my understanding is wrong about pointers and arrays.

Comment: A pointer is a variable that holds a memory address. An array **is** a memory address. Values held in pointer variables can be swapped. Array addresses assigned at compilation time cannot be swapped.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I'm sorry, but *"array is a memory address"* is nonsense. An array is a sequence of elements (that can be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element). A "memory address" is a value of a pointer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I misspoke... You misspoke... "_An array is a sequence of elements_" whose address "_can be implicitly converted to a pointer_" but cannot be changed at runtime... Sometimes we all speak too concisely...

Comment: It is a memory address tho. A constant one. Translate that into easier data. It is the same as the comparison between `x` declared as `int x` and `12`. `x` is a variable that can hold an integer value. `12` is an integer value. You can't modify 12. You can modify `x`. Arrays are to points what `12` is to `x`. It is just a constant value. A constant value of a memory address.

Comment: Now, you can of course have different vision for that. Mine (and Fe2O3) is more about how compiler deals with arrays. What `c` is for the compiler: it is a constant value, a constant memory address as 12 is (associated, of course, with some static meta data, like a type... like for 12). Now, a higher level vision, classically used, is to see the array as a bunch of variables elements stored consecutively in memory. But the "array is a constant memory address" view is a correct one. That you can read in many books.

Comment: "... A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type ..." https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1 -- your `c` has array type; your `h` has pointer type.

Comment: @chrslg An array is automatically converted to a pointer in most cases, but not all of them. It's not a pointer by itself. `&c` and `sizeof(c)` are examples of cases when it's not converted to a pointer, and the results you get from those operators make no sense if you only think of an array as a pointer. I see some C folks adopt a simplified mental model where "arrays are pointers, but `&` and `sizeof` have special meaning on arrays", but this model then breaks down when one then tries to learn C++, where you have many more cases where they don't convert (references to arrays, and so on).

Comment: OP: "_...  which is capable of swapping strings and arrays._" No. The code succeeds in swapping **pointers to strings**, but fails at the attempt to swap **arrays**... So much for writing _generic_ functions while still unsure about C's datatypes.

Comment: That's another question. I've never mentioned pointers. And I am not trying to learn C++, which is another language.

Comment: @chrslg: Re “It is a memory address tho”: No, it is not. The C standard is clear on this. An array **is** a contiguous sequence of objects of one type in memory. The fact an array **has** a fixed address does not mean the array **is** the address. Every object has a fixed address for its lifetime. Given `int x;`, `x` **has** a fixed address, but it **is not** that address. Your home **has** a fixed mailing address, but it **is not** that address. This is not merely a difference in words; it has concrete effects on how programs behave. Arrays are not addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> char c[5] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
> ```

Arrays are not pointers. `&c` is not `char **`.

Yes, you can do `*c` and `*(c + 2)` and other pointer-like things to an array, and it naturally makes you think it's a pointer, but it's not.

Those only work because an array is *implicitly converted* ("decays") to a pointer (to its first element) in many scenarios, including those ones. The resulting pointer is a temporary (an rvalue), it's computed on the fly when needed, and isn't stored in memory otherwise. The only thing stored in an array is its elements.

One of the cases where an array doesn't decay to a pointer is `&c`. This doesn't return `char **` (pointer to pointer to `char`), and this can't possibly work, because the pointer resulting from decay is computed, not persistently stored in the memory.

You instead get a pointer of type `char (*)[5]` (pointer to an array of `5` `char`s), which has the same value as `&c[0]`, but a different type (`&c[0]` is a `char *`).

Because there's no underlying pointer to swap, what you want is impossible.

The closest thing you can do is to go over each array element and swap it. This requires arrays to have the same length. Something like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void swap_memory(void *a, void *b, size_t n)
{
    char *ca = a;
    char *cb = b;
    char *end_ca = ca + n;
    while (ca != end_ca)
    {
        char tmp = *ca;
        *ca = *cb;
        *cb = tmp;
        ca++;
        cb++;
    }
}

void print_array(char *c, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%c ", c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char *h = "hell";
    char *w = "world";
    printf("%s %s\n", h, w);
    swap_memory(&h, &w, sizeof(char *));
    printf("%s %s\n", h, w);

    char c[5] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    char d[5] = { '1', '2', '3' };
    swap_memory(c, d, 5); // or `(&c, &d, 5)`, doesn't matter
    print_array(c, 3);
    print_array(d, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can design a generic swap function to swap objects of any type, but for the swap to be possible, the objects must have the same size. Here the string pointers do have the same size, `sizeof(char *)`, which is the same as `sizeof(void *)`, so your code should work as expected albeit it violates the strict aliasing rule. Conversely, `sizeof(c) != sizeof(d)` so swapping these arrays is not possible and furthermore, your swap function is not generic enough to swap objects whose size is not exactly that of a pointer.

The fundamental misunderstanding seems to be that arrays are **not** pointers. `h` and `w` are pointers to arrays of `char`, intialized to point to string literals, which are (non-modifiable) arrays of `char`, whereas `c` and `d` are actual arrays of resp. 6 and 4 bytes. Passing `c` to a function such as `print_array` does pass a pointer to their first elements, but that does not make them pointers.

Here is a modified version with a generic swap function with defined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t n) {
    unsigned char *aa = a;
    unsigned char *bb = b;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        unsigned char cc = aa[i];
        aa[i] = bb[i];
        bb[i] = cc;
    }
}

void print_array(const char *c, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%c ", c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    const char *h = "hell";
    const char *w = "world";
    printf("%s %s\n", h, w);
    swap(&h, &w, sizeof(h));
    printf("%s %s\n", h, w);

    char c[5] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    char d[5] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };
    print_array(c, sizeof(c));
    print_array(d, sizeof(d));
    swap(c, d, sizeof(c));
    print_array(c, sizeof(c));
    print_array(d, sizeof(d));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil:  Good point. Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the same function to swap pointers and to swap arrays.

For example to swap two arrays you need to swap their elements.

That is you can not exchange addresses of extents of memory occupeid by arrays. You can only exchange the contents of extents of memory occupied by arrays.

Here is a simple demonstration program that shows that to swap contents of two arrays you need to swap their pairs of elements

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array( const int a[], size_t n  ) 
{
    while ( n-- )
    {
        printf( "%02d ", *a++ );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 5 };
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 };
    int b[N] = { 10, 20, 30 ,40 ,50 };

    print_array( a, N );
    print_array( b, N );

    putchar( '\n' );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = tmp;
    }

    print_array( a, N );
    print_array( b, N );
}
```

The program output is

```
01 02 03 04 05
10 20 30 40 50

10 20 30 40 50
01 02 03 04 05
```

As for your function

```
void swap(void **a, void **b) {
    void *tmp;
    tmp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = tmp;
}
```

then it is clear seen for example from this declaration

```
void *tmp;
```

that it swaps only two pointers of the type `void *`. it is unable for example to swap two characters because `sizeof( char )` is less than `sizeof( void * )`.

As for the error then for example the value of the expression `&c` is the value of the address of the first element of the array `c`.

The operation of dereferencing of the address within the function `swap`

```
*b = *a;
```

reads the memory occupied by the array that is its elements `{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};` as a value of an address that results in undefined behavior.